# How to add SiteFeed Webpart or similar app to SharePoint Designer/InfoPath form?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, custom-form, sitefeed

Is there any way to add SiteFeed-Webpart in form via any means? Or any alternate method will be preferable?

Thanks

Comment: Which form you are talking about? Or you want to add SiteFeed webpart in SharePoint page?

Comment: is it possible to put the webpart in a form? or do i need to put it in a page only and then modify?

Comment: You could always edit the new/edit/display form and add any webparts that you like there above or below the actual form.

Comment: That is actually editing the page and adding webparts seprately ! Cool but is there any way to put sitefeed kind of thing inside the form via designer/infopath? it may be related to list too with whatever columns needed